# Is there branching functionality on a Google Apps Script Project?

Tags: google-apps-script, version-control, add-on, google-apps-script-api

I am new to Google Apps Script projects, and have a Google Calendar add-on that I have been working on. My users recently came across some bugs, and I realized that I had no idea how to go back to the version they were on, and save the current updates I was working on at the same time, like a github branch.

I did some research and couldn't find anything out online, so just want to know if there are any other alternatives other than pulling down all code locally and uploading it to my personal GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

To make your add-on go back to a previous version, just go to the Google Workspace Marketplace SDK and set the version number that you want to make available for your add-on users.

The Google Apps Script web editor it will always be showing the head deployment. You might use Google Apps Script API / CLASP to get access to any version. If you want to use the web editor, you should overwrite the files of with the version that you want to use.